# Use xsl variable to select class with jquery

Tags: jquery, xslt

Trying to use the variable to select a class, I've tried,

```
<xsl:variable name="aClassName"><xsl:text>sub</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="name" mode="translate"/></xsl:variable>

$('.'+$aClassName).removeClass('hide ');
```

but I get an error $aClassName is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `<xsl:value-of select="$aClassName"/>` in place of where you have `$aClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to implement this and Matthew Greens answer is incomplete to some extend, since simply replacing the values did not do the trick for me.

This was working for me though:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var  row = $('tr#<xsl:value-of select="$val"/>');
     row.show();
  });

</script>
```

Notice that there is no concatinating `+` and the single quotes surround the complete selector.